# Passing variables to ParDo from outside the pipeline in Dataflow

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

How can I pass a variable to ParDo function from outside the pipeline to Dataflow job. Below is an example and I am trying to derive the fileDate before creating the pipeline and want to pass it to ParDo function. I have the variable declared in interface

```
    public interface CsvToBq extends DataflowPipelineOptions {
    @Description("File Date")
    String getFileDate();

    void setFileDate(String value);
}
```

I am setting the value in job as

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    PipelineOptionsFactory.register(CsvToBq.class);
    CsvToBq options = PipelineOptionsFactory
            .fromArgs(args)
            .withValidation()
            .as(CsvToBq.class);

    Date date = new Date();     
    String fileDate = formatter.format(date);
    options.setFileDate(fileDate);
```

and I am accessing the variable in ParDo function as

```
 private static class WikiParDo extends DoFn<String, TableRow> {
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {

        PipelineOptions options = c.getPipelineOptions();
        String fileDate = options.getFileDate();
        String[] split = c.element().split(",");
        TableRow row = new TableRow();
        for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
            TableFieldSchema col = getTableSchema().getFields().get(i);
            row.set(col.getName(), split[i]);
        }
        row.set("file_date", fileDate);
        c.output(row);
    }
}
```

Here is the complete code

```
public class CsvToBq {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PipelineOptionsFactory.register(CsvToBq.class);
    CsvToBq options = PipelineOptionsFactory
            .fromArgs(args)
            .withValidation()
            .as(CsvToBq.class);

    Date date = new Date();     
    String fileDate = formatter.format(date);
    options.setFileDate(fileDate);

    Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);
    pipeline.apply("READ", TextIO.read().from("gs://bucket/file.csv"))
            .apply("TRANSFORM", ParDo.of(new WikiParDo()))
            .apply("WRITE", BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
                    .to(String.format("%s:dataset_name.wiki_demo", options.getProject()))
                    .withCreateDisposition(CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
                    .withWriteDisposition(WRITE_TRUNCATE)
                    .withSchema(getTableSchema()));
    pipeline.run();
}

private static TableSchema getTableSchema() {
    List<TableFieldSchema> fields = new ArrayList<>();
    fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("year").setType("INTEGER"));
    fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("month").setType("INTEGER"));
    fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("day").setType("INTEGER"));
    fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("wikimedia_project").setType("STRING"));
    fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("language").setType("STRING"));
    fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("title").setType("STRING"));
    fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("views").setType("INTEGER"));
    fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("file_date").setType("STRING"));
    return new TableSchema().setFields(fields);
}

public interface CsvToBq extends DataflowPipelineOptions {
    @Description("File Date")
    String getFileDate();

    void setFileDate(String value);
}

private static class WikiParDo extends DoFn<String, TableRow> {
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {

        PipelineOptions options = c.getPipelineOptions();
        String fileDate = options.getFileDate();

        String[] split = c.element().split(",");
        TableRow row = new TableRow();
        for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
            TableFieldSchema col = getTableSchema().getFields().get(i);
            row.set(col.getName(), split[i]);
        }
        row.set("file_date", fileDate);
        c.output(row);
    }
}
```

}

But this doesnt work. I tried using StaticValueProvider and sideinputs but looks like it doesnt serve the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need something like:

```
    CsvToBq options = c.getPipelineOptions().as(CsvToBq.class);
    String fileDate = options.getFileDate();
```

Also, if you are not planning on using ValueProviders ( [a current requirement for passing parameters to Dataflow templates](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates) ) , you can also do something like this:

```
private static class WikiParDo extends DoFn<String, TableRow> {
String fileName;
  public WikiParDo(String fileName) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
  }
```

Note what you store needs to be serlizable. joda.time Instant objects if I recall are ok.

Comment: Did you fix your compile issue?

Comment: Was not able to get the compile error through , I got it done using ValueProviders, will post the code shortly. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I got this done using StaticValueProvider. More on this can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates#staticvalue)

We need to define the interface that extends the options as below

```
    @Description("File Date")
    ValueProvider<String[]> getFileDate();
    void setFileDate(ValueProvider<String[]> value);
```

In the main method we can set the variable as

```
    Date date = new Date();
    String fileDate = formatter.format(date);
```

and can be passed in the pipeline appy transform as

```
ParDo.of(new WikiParDo(StaticValueProvider.of(fileDate)))
```

and in the ParDo function we can use as below

```
    ValueProvider<String[]> fDate;
    StoreFrontBqConv(ValueProvider<String[]> fileDate) {
      this.fDate = fileDate;
    }

    fDate.get()
```

Here is the complete code

```
public class CsvToBq {

public interface CsvToBq extends DataflowPipelineOptions {
    @Description("File Date")
    ValueProvider<String[]> getFileDate();
    void setFileDate(ValueProvider<String[]> value);
}

private static class WikiParDo extends DoFn<String, TableRow> {

    ValueProvider<String[]> fDate;
    StoreFrontBqConv(ValueProvider<String[]> fileDate) {
      this.fDate = fileDate;
    }

    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {

        PipelineOptions options = c.getPipelineOptions();

        String[] split = c.element().split(",");
        TableRow row = new TableRow();
        for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
            TableFieldSchema col = getTableSchema().getFields().get(i);
            row.set(col.getName(), split[i]);
        }
        row.set("file_date", fDate.get());
        c.output(row);
    }
}

private static TableSchema getTableSchema() {
    List<TableFieldSchema> fields = new ArrayList<>();
    fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("year").setType("INTEGER"));
    fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("month").setType("INTEGER"));
    fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("day").setType("INTEGER"));
    fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("wikimedia_project").setType("STRING"));
    fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("language").setType("STRING"));
    fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("title").setType("STRING"));
    fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("views").setType("INTEGER"));
    fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("file_date").setType("STRING"));
    return new TableSchema().setFields(fields);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    PipelineOptionsFactory.register(CsvToBq.class);
    CsvToBq options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(CsvToBq.class);

    Date date = new Date();
    String fileDate = formatter.format(date);

    Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);
    pipeline.apply("READ", TextIO.read().from("gs://bucket/file.csv"))
            .apply("TRANSFORM", ParDo.of(new WikiParDo(StaticValueProvider.of(fileDate)))).apply("WRITE",
                    BigQueryIO.writeTableRows().to(String.format("%s:dataset_name.wiki_demo", options.getProject()))
                            .withCreateDisposition(CREATE_IF_NEEDED).withWriteDisposition(WRITE_TRUNCATE)
                            .withSchema(getTableSchema()));
    pipeline.run();
}
```

}